# Why would you check that fscanf returns value < 1 in a function?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I was given a problem to solve using fscanf which states the following:

*Write a function to initialize array x of size SIZE with integers read from a text file. The function receives the name of the file as an argument.*

The solution states the following below. Why would fscanf return a value < 1 if you're scanning each integer in the file? Shouldn't it be > 0 since fscanf returns the number of elements scanned?

```
void init (char *name)
{
    FILE    *fp;
    int i;

    fp = fopen (name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("no file\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &x[i]) < 1)
        {
            printf ("got %d numbers\n", i);
            return;
        }
    }

    fclose (fp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: So if it returns < 1 then it didn't scan anything. Perhaps you've run out of data? perhaps there is an error?

Comment: Read the man page. It says `the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.`.

Comment: If you are on Linux you can simply type `man fscanf` in terminal to open the API reference manual of `fscanf` and you can read the section under _**return value**_. This goes for any function call.

Comment: @Gaurav yeah I did read the manual and I'm still confused which is why I'm asking on here.... 

am I correct in thinking that this if statement is written to break the for loop  when the fscanf returns a value < 1 which is essentially the EOF?

Comment: @Connor, it's not just EOF, it will also fail if it finds something like `hello`, or the `.14159` bit of `3.14159`. Basically, anything that's not a valid integer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding the intent of the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &x[i]) < 1)
    {
        printf ("got %d numbers\n", i);
        return;
    }
}
```

What this will do is return if the `fscanf` *failed* to read in an integer (it returns the number of items scanned). So, at that point, the function will return<sup>(a)</sup>.

If you get a positive integer, it means you successfully read in the value and your loop will continue.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You probably should `break` here rather than return since the file doesn't get closed the way it is at the moment.

Comment: Probably, OP should replace `printf` with `perror`, in this way it should also print what error actually made `fscanf` to return 0.

Comment: @Gaurav -- `errno` is not set just because a user fails to enter an integer when expected by `fscanf()`.... In other words, `perror()` is probably going to be useless here.

Comment: @paxdiablo so basically this is just a long winded way of breaking when fscanf is no longer able to read integers in the file?

Comment: @DavidBowling Ohh, I thought that `perror` should print the errno in this case as well if `fscanf` fails.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks, I just read it in the duplicate link. Got it. (y)

Comment: @Connor: yes, basically. It will loop up to `SIZE` times but break out early if you run out of valid input values.

Comment: @Stargateur -- it is a POSIX requirement that `errno` be set if an error occurs before the first conversion has completed, but I don't anywhere in the C11 Standard that `fscanf()` must set `errno` or any error indicators.

Answer (score 0):

> Why would fscanf return a value < 1 if you're scanning each integer in the file?

`fscanf (fp, "%d", &x[i])` returns:

`1` when **one** `int` scanned successfully.  Code loops to read additional `int`

`0` when only non-numeric non-white-space input detected

`EOF` (`EOF` is some negative value) on end-of-file.

`EOF` on input error (rare).

---

With `if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &x[i]) < 1)`, the branch is taken as one of the last 3 conditions occurred - likely end-of-file.